# Google Colab - Toggle to Hide/Unhide cells

Tags: toggle, hide, google-colaboratory

In Google Colab - how do I hide/unhide cells under a section or subsection

Answer (score 0):

There's a triangle in front of each heading.

If you click at that triangle, it will toggle between show and hide.